# How to convert .pages file format from apple to pdf on windows linux programmatically

Tags: ios, windows, macos, pdf-generation, file-format

How to convert .pages file format from apple to pdf on windows linux programmatically with some code.

I have tried few things like changing the extension to .zip and then unzip.

This gives me the content although the contents are images text in an xml file and a plist file. Which combined will create the file.

Tried MS Office to convert but not all the .pages files get converted.

Analysed iCloud but I am not sure if there is an SDK for windows which can convert the file in pdf format.

Any information around how to convert the .pages file to pdf will be very much appreciated.

Comment: what does zip file have to do with a pages file.  If a file is zipped it should be unzipped using gunzip filename.  Then if the unzipped file is a pages document the extension will be pages.

Comment: .pages file is basically a zipped file with .pages as extension. The content of the .pages files can be seen by doing show content on mac.
Although my question basically was how to convert the .pages files to .pdf through code. I should have explained the question a little better I guess. Have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iCloud account, go to http://www.icloud.com and log in. Once logged in, click on the Pages icon. You can then drag-and-drop your pages document into the window. Once it's uploaded, move your mouse over the document and click the '...' button and select 'Download a copy.' Select 'PDF,' and there you go.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Although I am looking for a solution which is possible through code. iCloud does the conversion although I am not sure of any API / SDK shared by apple or anyone to do the same.